# Why the PNG image resized and shows very well in UIImageView but quality not good when I draw it by CGContextDrawImage

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a PNG (52x52) image file,if I show it in a UIImageView (16x16) , it is showed good.

But if I try to use CGContextDrawImage to draw, the quality is very bad.

Please see below detail code:

resizeImage is used to resize the image (copy from apple site).
drawStonesPng is do draw the image and called form CALayer:: drawInContext

```
- (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image toWidth:(NSInteger)width height:(NSInteger)height
{
    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Flip the context because UIKit coordinate system is upside down to Quartz coordinate system
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Draw the original image to the context
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height), image.CGImage);

    // Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
    UIImage *imageOut = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageOut;
}



-(void)drawStonesPng:(CGContextRef)ctx{

    _cellWidth=16;
    float x1,y1;
    float f1=0.48;

   // self.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    UIImage* resizedImageBlack = [self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackstone52"] toWidth:_cellWidth*f1*2 height:_cellWidth*f1*2];
    UIImage* resizedImageBlackShadow = [self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackshadow"] toWidth:_cellWidth*f1*2 height:_cellWidth*f1*2];
    CGImageRef imgBlack = [resizedImageBlack CGImage];
    CGImageRef imgBlackShadow = [resizedImageBlackShadow CGImage];
    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgBlack), height = CGImageGetHeight(imgBlack);


//    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);
//    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx, true);
    for(int y=0; y<_boardSize; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<_boardSize; x++) {

            STONE_T stone = [MyGoController getStoneType:x y:y];
            if(STONE_INVALID==stone){
                CGContextClosePath(ctx);
                return;
            }

            if(stone==STONE_BLACK){

                x1=(x+1)*_cellWidth-_cellWidth*f1;
                y1=(y+1)*_cellWidth-_cellWidth*f1;



//                CGFloat scale = _cellWidth*0.9/width;
//                NSLog(@"Scale: %f\nWidth: %f\nHeight: %f", scale, width, height);
//                CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, height / scale);
//                CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);


                CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

                self.contentsScale =[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

                NSLog(@"Scale: %f\nWidth: %f\nHeight: %f", scale, width, height);
                CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, width / scale);
                CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);


                CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(x1+1, y1+1, width/scale,width/scale), imgBlackShadow);
                CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(x1, y1, width/scale,width/scale), imgBlack);



            }

        }
    }

    resizedImageBlack = [self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whitestone52"] toWidth:_cellWidth*f1*2 height:_cellWidth*f1*2];
    resizedImageBlackShadow = [self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteshadow"] toWidth:_cellWidth*f1*2 height:_cellWidth*f1*2];
    imgBlack = [resizedImageBlack CGImage];
    imgBlackShadow = [resizedImageBlackShadow CGImage];

    //draw white stones

    for(int y=0; y<_boardSize; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<_boardSize; x++) {
            STONE_T stone = [MyGoController getStoneType:x y:y];

            if(stone==STONE_WHITE){

                x1=(x+1)*_cellWidth-_cellWidth*f1;
                y1=(y+1)*_cellWidth-_cellWidth*f1;



                //                CGFloat scale = _cellWidth*0.9/width;
                //                NSLog(@"Scale: %f\nWidth: %f\nHeight: %f", scale, width, height);
                //                CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, height / scale);
                //                CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);


                CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(x1+1, y1+1, _cellWidth*f1*2,_cellWidth*f1*2), imgBlackShadow);
                CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(x1, y1, _cellWidth*f1*2,_cellWidth*f1*2), imgBlack);





            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use UIImageView though?

Comment: I am working on board game app, and I use a CALayer to draw all the chess picture (max to 181 stones) on it.

Comment: Are you checking the size of Original image and the Rect that you are passing ? And Can you pls provide the definition of 'ctx' (Context), because the Rect specified in Context definition may affect the quality

Comment: The Original size is 52x52 , and i need it be draw as 16x16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content scale of the layer you're using :

```
CALayer theLayer = ....;
theLayer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale
```

Comment: Do you have a example for detail, I subclass the CALayer and draw a lot of small image on it

Comment: Not sure what examples I could provide more than the sample code I posted

Comment: When you create your layer to draw those chess piece, you do something like ChessLayer* chessLayer = [[ChessLayer alloc] init]; or something. With that object "chessLayer" just do chessLayer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

Comment: Aha, now it works , when I move the contentScale outside of drawInContext and put them on parentView.Thanks for all!